# VirtualBox 7.0.10

Tags: apt, package-management, virtualbox, dependencies

I'm a beginner, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 and now it wants to install VirtualBox 7.0.10, but during installation it says:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of virtualbox-7.0:
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5core5a (>= 5.15.1); however:
  Package libqt5core5a is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5dbus5 (>= 5.14.1); however:
  Package libqt5dbus5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5gui5 (>= 5.14.1) | libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.14.1); however:
  Package libqt5gui5 is not installed.
  Package libqt5gui5-gles is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5help5 (>= 5.15.1); however:
  Package libqt5help5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5opengl5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5opengl5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5printsupport5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5printsupport5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5widgets5 (>= 5.15.1); however:
  Package libqt5widgets5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.6.0); however:
  Package libqt5x11extras5 is not installed.
 virtualbox-7.0 depends on libqt5xml5 (>= 5.0.2); however:
  Package libqt5xml5 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-7.0 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.70+nmu1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.26-1ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.1-2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-7.0
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa)

Comment: Why does "it wants to install VirtualBox 7.0.10,"?

Comment: the version of Virtualbox tested, compatible, and packaged in the Ubuntu 20.04 repositories* with 20.04 is Vbox 6.1. Either use a newer release of Ubuntu that is compatible with 7.0 or use the older release of Virtualbox that is in the 20.04 Ubuntu repositories. It's curious that you installed 20.04, which is three years old: Much newer releases are offered on the Ubuntu download page.

Comment: VirtualBox version 7.0.10 is currently only provided for the beta version of Ubuntu (code name ***mantic***): https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=virtualbox&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all